# How to get text from entry

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I create an entry using

```
 <Entry Placeholder="Reply..."/>
```

It is inside a ListView > ItemTemplate > DataTemplate > ViewCell

The thing is I need a way once a user clicks the submit button in that ViewCell it gets the text for the entry in that cell. I am using Binding to set the values so I don't how to get the text.

Comment: Please,  share the relevant viewcell code. The entry's text default mode is twoway, so when you change the entrys text your bound object is changed too

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza https://gist.github.com/KingBlueSapphire/8e38edc468b02a087c3462f4cd5d5236

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza That's all my relevant code

Comment: You access the data through each `element` of the `ItemsSource` of your `ListView`. That's the cleanest approach. You only need to get the appropriate index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing your code I could notice why the @sme's answer doesn't fit you. You're making a very confusing and poor use of [`bindings`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/) and [`xaml`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/), and I'm quite sure that move to [`MVVM`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/) is the best thing you can do now.

But, if you insist to keep the code like it is now, you can just add the Reply text bound to the Entry's text property, like that:

```
<Entry Placeholder="Reply..." 
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
       Margin="0, 0, 0, 5"
       Text="{Binding Reply}"/>
```

So, as you are sending the entire `MessageObject`object to the tap command, you'll be able to get the text content just this way:

```
public void ReplyCommandClick(string id, object msg)
{
    MessageObject message = (MessageObject) msg;
    message.ShowReplyField = message.ShowReplyField ? false : true;
    //var viewcell = (MessageObject)((Label)msg).BindingContext;
    //viewcell. // There were no options for the entry
    var reply = msg.Reply;
    SendReply(id, msg, reply);
}
```

Comment: Usually it's just the actual Model when you're using a command binded to a `ViewCell`. Or the common event params(sender, event) when adding an event handler for each cells

Comment: @mr5 I'm sorry, I couldn't understand what you mean. My English is too poor

Answer (score 4):

When you handle the button's click event, assuming you are using an event handler to listen to the `Clicked` event, you can get the `BindingContext` of the button (which should also be the same `BindingContext` for the entire ViewCell).

Like so:

```
public void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Assuming the List bound to the ListView contains "MyObject" objects,
    // for example List<MyObject>:

    var myObjectBoundToViewCell = (MyObject)((Button)sender).BindingContext;

    // and now use myObjectBoundToViewCell to get the text that is bound from the Entry
}
```

Comment: I don't have the text bound to an entry? This is my code https://gist.github.com/KingBlueSapphire/8e38edc468b02a087c3462f4cd5d5236 I can't find any way to get the entry

Comment: I couldn't find anything related to the Entry in 'myObjectBoundToViewCell '

Comment: Maybe you need to add Text="{Binding PostReply}" to your <Entry>. Although Im not sure if thats the field you want to use. But you need to bind the Entry's Text property to some property in MessageObject at least